# User-backed allocation failed stride requirement, falling back to separate allocation

Tags: java, android, xml, renderscript

When I use [blur](https://github.com/wonderkiln/BlurKit-Android), I got an info:

`RenderScript: User-backed allocation failed stride requirement, falling back to separate allocation`

I saw that someone wrote that It isn't dangerous but I want to solve this problem. Does anybody have an idea?

Here is the implementation:

```
<com.wonderkiln.blurkit.BlurLayout 
    android:id="@+id/blurred_area"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

</com.wonderkiln.blurkit.BlurLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your layout_width and thus the width of the bitmap to the blur should be aligned by 4, 8 or 16. Try different alignments until the message goes away.